# JS или CSS - Высота двух дивок равна наим. из них

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка

Есть две дивки с разной высотой (1).

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы их высота была равна наименьшей из них (2). 
Собственно возможно ли это реализовать без js?
[image: Пример]

Comment: Т. е. сделать колонки равной высоты? Или куда делся кусок первой колонки на втором рисунке?

Comment: Если это строчные/строчноблочные элементы, то высота будет подстраиваться под контент - что тогда делать с большим блоком? Обрезать контент? А если блочные, тогда откуда берётся ненужная бОльшая высота?

Comment: А наименьший блок всегда разной высоты или одинаковой? Если одинаковой, то достаточно max-height. Если разной, то тут надо JS.

Answer (score 2):

Можно благодаря display:flex [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRZLVa#anon-login)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>

.container {
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  .one, .two {
    width:  40%;
    background: #ccc;
    margin:  10px 20px;
  } 
  .two {
    height:  400px;
  }
}
```